# Wise and Bold - Single Word Request

Tags: single-word-requests

Word that means both wise and bold. 
Bold, under normal terms, seems to be contradictory.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 1):

Boldness and wisdom are not antonyms, by any means, but are concepts unrelated enough that they are difficult to capture in a single word.

I think dauntless is a pretty good fit, however.  Although it doesn't include wisdom, exactly, it implies a mental or spiritual as well as physical fortitude.

Per oxford dictionary (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dauntless):

> daunt·less
>   [ˈdôntləs, ˈdäntləs]
>
> ADJECTIVE
>   showing fearlessness and determination.
>
> "dauntless bravery"
>
> synonyms:
>   fearless · determined · resolute · indomitable · intrepid · doughty · plucky · spirited · game · mettlesome · gritty · steely · confident · undaunted · undismayed · unalarmed

Comment: Hi Meg!  Please cite the source for your definition in your answer.